# Resetear un array en angular 13

Tags: angular

Tengo una duda desde hace varios días con Angular y la programación reactiva.

Estoy cargando información en el componente implementando una interfaz ngOnInit

```
export class WebsiteListComponent implements OnInit  {
  
  quoteArray: Ticker[] = [];
  users: Ticker[]=[];
  pagination: boolean;
  page: number;
  size: number;
  data: Ticker[] = [];
  interval: any;
  i = 0;


  constructor(private customerService: WebsiteService, private quoteBlockingService: WebsiteService) {
    this.pagination = true;
    this.page = 0;
    this.size = 50;
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
     
    setInterval(() => {    
      this.users = [];
      this.customerService.getMyEventSourceStream()
      .subscribe(
        (newUser) => {
           this.users = this.users.concat(newUser);
           console.log(this.users);
        }
      )
    }, 1000);
      
  }
  
  }
```

El HTML a continuación

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let contact of users">
        {{contact.id}}
        {{contact.symbol}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Esto me pinta el array en la consola de la siguiente forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando pongo el this.users = []; en la consola me lo pinta bien pero en el HTML no y no se porqué sucede esto.

```
 setInterval(() => {    
          this.users = [];
          this.customerService.getMyEventSourceStream()
          .subscribe(
            (newUser) => {
               this.users = this.users.concat(newUser);
               console.log(this.users);
            }
          )
        }, 1000);
```

En el HTML se visualiza de la siguiente forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría ayudarme la verdad que estoy bastante amargado con esto.

Aañado el código del servicio que básicamente hace una llamada de forma reactiva.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsiteService {
    private customersList: Ticker[] = new Array();
    
    private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:9001';
    
    constructor( 
      private _http: HttpClient,
      private _zone: NgZone
    ) { }

  getMyEventSourceStream():Observable<Ticker> {
    return new Observable<Ticker>((observer) => {      
      let eventSource = new EventSource(this.baseUrl);
      console.log("EventSource"+eventSource);      
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        let json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        observer.next(new Ticker(json['id']));
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {        
        if(eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
          eventSource.close();
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: hay algo que no veo claro, ¿Por qué si declaras `users: Ticker[]=[];` vuelves en ngOnInit a declarar `this.users = [];`?

Comment: @RodolfoBarbeitoRodriguez mi intención cada vez que hago un setInterval es que ese array se inicialize de nuevo. Esto funciona a medias y por ahi creo que anda la cosa..

Comment: probaste con ngAfterViewInit() para cargar la informacion ? no mostras  tu codigo customerService  asi que no se si mi consulta puede ser correcta

Comment: @nestdan no lo he probado .. voy a ver acabo de adjuntar el service

Comment: Donde usas _zone: NgZone? no lo mostras en el codigo Si lo usas como  this._zone.runOutsideAngular(()=>) para que se ejecute el setInterval () no se pinta el codigo porque users  se esta actualizando fuera de NgZone no actualiza a la vista se pierde al binding Hay que acceder al DOM entonces mediante una template reference variable  y valiendose de sus propiedades setearlo dentro del metodo anterior para actualizarlo por ejmplo con ElementRef

Comment: si mostras como usas NgZone creo te podran aconsejar constructor(private _zone: NgZone) { 
  this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    setInterval(() => {}, 1000); // se ejecuta fuera de la zona Angular
    this._zone.run(() => {
      // se ejecuta dentro de la zona de angular
    });

Answer (score 0):

**Hay que notificar a Angular del cambio con this.zone.run()**

> Para que se ejecute el binding  del observable en la vista
> provenientes del EventSource.  Necesitamos NgZone para alertar a
> Angular cuando ocurre un evento porque sucede fuera de su alcance.
> Se debe establecer  en tu codigo mediante:

```js
this.zone.run(() => observer.next(...)
```

Tambien podes ver si te puede ser de utilidad   conectarte a Server Sent Events (SSE) utilizando Event Source API en el link [Angular y SSE](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-and-server-sent-events-sse-54c29b4f174d)
En tu codigo usando solamente EventSource notificamos a Angular con this.zone.run():

```js
private zone: NgZone
private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:9001';
//Hay que notificar a Angular del cambio con this.zone.run()
eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
         let json = JSON.parse(event.data);
      this.zone.run(() => observer.next(new Ticker(json['id'])));
    };
```

Si no modificas tu codigo con this.zone.run() podrias notificar a Angular con templete referencias y elementRef o crear Observables internos con los cuales puedas comunicar  a Angular los cambios que no puede detectar en tu caso podes crear a un  BehaviorSubject que te permite reiniciarlo  comunicar sus nuevos valores y setearlo [como Gestionar BehaviorSubject](https://rneto.es/blog/gestionar-estado-angular-rxjs-behaviorsubject-servicios-datos-observables/)
Pero si simplemente comunicas con ***this.zone.run()*** no tenes necesidad de agregar una deteccion adicional  pues Eventsource permite a un cliente recibir actualizaciones automáticas de un servidor y si lo comunicas con  **this.zone.run()** se vera reflejado en la vista
Otra posible solucion creando un
BehaviorSubject([]) al cual subscribirse en tu servicio [Ejemplo con EventSource the real-time exchange rate](https://ramya-bala221190.medium.com/simple-example-to-demonstrate-server-sent-events-in-angular-and-node-ea9979b6e19)

**Se actualiza el array sin necesidad de  setInterval() si se define correctamente la deteccion del cambio**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { EventSourceService } from '../event-source.service';
import { mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event',
  templateUrl: './event.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event.component.css']
})


export class EventComponent implements

OnInit {
  
url='http://localhost:8888';
data=[0];

  constructor(private eventSourceService:EventSourceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
   this.eventSourceService.getServerSentEvent('http://localhost:8888/countdown').subscribe(data => {this.data=[...data.data,data],console.log(this.data)});

  }}
```

```html
{{data |json}}
```

```js
//servicio
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
//ng g m about --route=about -m app-routing.module.ts
export class EventSourceService {

  constructor(private zone:NgZone) { }
  private getEventSource(url: string): EventSource {
    return new EventSource(url);
}

getServerSentEvent(url: string): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        const eventSource = this.getEventSource(url);

        eventSource.onmessage = event => {
            this.zone.run(() => observer.next(event));

        };
    });
}
}
```

```js
//app.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.get('/countdown',cors() ,function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  })
  countdown(res, 3)
})

function countdown(res, count) {
  res.write("data: " + [count ]+ "\n\n")
  //res.send([1, 2, 3]);
  if (count)
    setTimeout(() => countdown(res, count-1), 1000)
  else
    res.end()
}

app.listen(8888, () => console.log('SSE app listening on port 8888!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco arcaico la implementación, pero funcional. Podrías servirte de las bondades de rxjs.

```
import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

users$: Observable<Ticker[]>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.users$ = timer( 0, 1000 ) // El operador timer permite crear un observable que emite un valor cada cierto tiempo
    .pipe( // El operador pipe permite aplicar una serie de operaciones sobre un observable
      mergeMap( () => // El operador mergeMap permite crear un observable a partir de otro observable
      this.customerService.getMyEventSourceStream()
      ))
  }
```

Ahora tienes un Observable al que puedes suscribirte con una llamada a tu API y un delay de 1000ms, pero en lugar de hacerlo en el `.ts`, hazlo en el `.html` con el pipe de `async`, eso te suscribirá sin necesidad de hacerlo en el `.ts` y hará un `unsubscribe()` cuando se destruya el componente, así no haces un memory leak.

El HTML luciría así mas o menos

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let contact of users$ | async">
        {{contact.id}}
        {{contact.symbol}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Te incluyo la documentación

1. [timer()](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer)
2. [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap)
3. [asyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)